# Trying to keep item at bottom of page

Tags: android, jquery, css

In android I'm having big issues keeping my div / bg image at the bottom of the page.

So I'm trying to move the entire sidebar item while you scroll but something is screwy with my math / code.

So I offer to you this attempt to discover what I a-matter with my logic:

```
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        var current = jQuery('.side-bar').css('background-position', '-43px', '0%' + parseInt(+y / 10) + '%');
        current();
        console.log(current;);
    });
```

Comment: How does the `android` tag apply here?

Comment: I guess it does if the issue is with android.

Comment: with android 2.2 background position: 0 100%; doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DIV and use `position:fixed` and `bottom:0px;`.